# DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet - How to avoid popupui=1 on Windows Live?

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth, windows-live

In contrast to all the other questions I've found here on SO, I DON'T want a popup window. The trouble is that it seems by default that with Windows Live/Microsoft Account DotNetOpenAuth seems to set `popupui=1` on the query string from `RequestAuthentication` by default.

There's a `UIMode` enum but that only seems to have the single value `popup`.

Does anyone know how to prevent it doing this?

#### update

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx) Windows Live has a `display` parameter which accepts `touch`, `page`, `popup` or `none`. Unfortunately, "page" results in `popupui=1` in exactly the same way as "popup" does.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this isn't possible after all;

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90a2d464-afd9-44ba-970c-8290353a259d/how-do-i-avoid-windows-live-appending-popopui1-to-my-authorize-request?forum=messengerconnect